# Cortana notifies about upcoming Travel dates

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana, nokia-lumia-1320

I am having Windows Lumia 1320 which has windows 10 OS installed in it. It also has Cortana feature.

Couple of months back my friend booked journey tickets using my wallet account from his android mobile phone and yesterday all of a sudden Cortana notified me about that upcoming travel journey.

So how that can be possible that Cortana is notifying me about that upcoming travel journey even though that travel ticket was not booked from my lumia phone?

Do i need to be worried about this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that you're talking about the most intrusive tool ever created.
Microsoft merge emails, messages, location, ETC. in order to show you a maximum of informations. - Maybe your friend send you an email with it ? - Does he added you to a Google calendar event and Cortana saw this ?

Comment: No. He didnt send me any email. Neither he added me to any google event.